# Как декорировать импортированные функции в Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, декоратор

ДЕнь добрый.
Изучаю декорирование и не могу понять ...

1-ый вопрос

Есть файл с исходной функцией `def name1():`
Создаю файл для декорирования и пишу

```
from file_name import name1

def decorator(fun):
    def wrapper():
        "некий код"
       response = fun()

       return response
    return wrapper
```

Далее не могу сделать так

```
@decorator
name1
```

или

```
@decorator
name1()
```

или

```
n = name1

@decorator
n
```

получаю ошибку и в консоле пусто. Понять не могу.
Как декорировать импортированные функции?

2-ой вопрос

Есть три страницы

```
basic_function.py "- базовый код"
decorators.py "декораторы"
main.py "-запускаем декораторы"
```

`basic_function`
содержит функцию

```
@decorator
def name1()
```

`decorators.py`
содержит декоратор

```
def decorator(fun):
    def wrapper():
        "некий код"
       response = fun()

       return response
    return wrapper
```

Страница `main` или пусть `decorators.py`
Как запустить `decorator(fun)` ?

Если надо уже `name1()` импортировать на страницу `decorators.py` , тогда вопрос
Зачем нужен `@` если `name1()`  в `wrapper()` легко вставляется и без декоратора?

---

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`decorated_name1 = decorator(name1)`

Или разбить по модулям так, чтобы наоборот импортировать декоратор в file_name и там декорировать name1 при создании.

Comment: данный `decorated_name1 = decorator(name1)` способ понятный. 

Значит если функция импортируемая, использовать через `@decorator` уже не получится?

Comment: Конечно. Он навешивается при определении функции. Если надо именно так, то это решается правильной структурой проекта.

Comment: о какой правильной структуре речь идет? Есть стандарт или что?
Базовые функции в одном фалей, декоратор в другом .

Comment: @Tryd0g0lik Стандарта не назову. Но смысл разделить по модулям, а модули по смыслу в соответствии с подходами SOLID. Тут без контекста не предложишь. Разве что явная рекомендация это избегать циклических импортов.

Comment: Спасибо. В отношении модулей понимание есть

Answer (score 0):

2. не нужно запускать decorator(fun). Если я правильно понял, то функция decorator это декоратор, а декораторы нужны для того, чтобы менять поведение других функции, а не для их отдельного выполнения.
   Импортировать name1  в main, выполнить её там и она выполнится отдекорированной